# ng-file-upload $file null after first use

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ng-file-upload

When I upload an image, it works very well !
But once every two the $file is null Just before sending it...

```
    <button ngf-select="upload($file)"
       ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
       ngf-accept="'image/*'"
       multiple
       class="btn btn-success">
    Add</button>
```

JS:

```
$scope.upload = function (file) {
  console.log(file)
  Upload.upload({
    data: {resource: file},
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/resource/parking/' + $scope.parking._id,
    headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer' + $auth.getToken()}
  }).then(function (response) {
    getParking();
    $scope.messagesConfigurationGalerie = {
      success: Array.isArray(response.data) ? response.data : [response.data]
    };
  })
    .catch(function (response) {
      $scope.messagesConfigurationGalerie = {
        error: Array.isArray(response.data) ? response.data : [response.data]
      };
    });
};
```

the console.log(file) is Null once every two 
Ty

Answer (score 0):

If I reload the page between each upload, it works ...